# What does this declaration means? struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_init(void)

Tags: c, pointers, curl, struct, function-declaration

```
struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_init(void)
{
  CURLcode result;
  struct Curl_easy *data;

  /* Make sure we inited the global SSL stuff */
  if(!initialized) {
    result = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    if(result) {
      /* something in the global init failed, return nothing */
      DEBUGF(fprintf(stderr, "Error: curl_global_init failed\n"));
      return NULL;
    }
  }

  /* We use curl_open() with undefined URL so far */
  result = Curl_open(&data);
  if(result) {
    DEBUGF(fprintf(stderr, "Error: Curl_open failed\n"));
    return NULL;
  }

  return data;
}
```

struct Curl_easy *curl_easy_init(void){}

What does this declaration means? Is there any proper keyword can I google about this? I tried Function Pointer Struct, Struct pointer, etc....

Comment: [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+Curl_easy+*curl_easy_init%28void%29) can sometimes help. But a good book is better. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303)

Comment: Wow thx what a helpful site!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
struct Curl_easy * curl_easy_init(void)
```

is a declaration of a function with the name `curl_easy_init` that has the pointer return type `struct Curl_easy *` and no parameters.

In case of success the function returns the updated pointer

```
struct Curl_easy *data;
```

declared within the function. Otherwise the function returns `NULL`.

Comment: Thx! I understand. I voted ur ans, but I'm newbee.. so vote don't go up. Please understand

Comment: @Http2inc Just mark the answer as the best answer.